# Scala what does arrow symbol in sequence mean?

Tags: scala, sequence

While looking at an open source code I found out that sometimes some people use syntax like this:

```
Seq[Date => String]
```

Can you please explain what does this mean and how it is used? I am new to Scala.

Answer (score 3):

```
Seq[Date => String]
```

Is a sequence of functions from `Date` (taking in a parameter of type `Date`) to `String` (returning a `String`). It is *syntactic sugar* for [`Function1[Date, String]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/Function1.html):

```
Seq[Function1[Date, String]]
```

For example, one could use:

```
val x = List[Date => String](date => date.toString)
```

Which, when invoked, would print the `toString` method of the `Date` class.

Answer (score 1):

It means this is a sequence of *Functions from Date to String*. In Scala, functions are first-class citizens, which means (among other things) that functions have *types*. `A => B` is the notation describing the type of a function that takes an argument of type A and returns a value of type B.

For example, you can write:

```
val f1: Date => String = d => d.toString
def f2(d: Date): String = d.toString
val s: Seq[Date => String] = Seq(f1, f2)
```